# how to check if a column as a repeated (deliberate) sequence in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I have a data frame (mdata -> 2106796 x 3) that has a column named "wavelength". This column has sequences of numbers from 350 to 1349, 1401 to 1799, and 1951 to 2999 (from 350 to 2999 some numbers were excluded). I was checking the data randomly and I observed that some "wavelength" for particular "ID" have the counting backward, from 2999 to 350 (with all the missing numbers mentioned above). I found a way to overcome this problem using this code:
`mdata <- mdata %>% arrange(targt_ID, wavelength)`

Now I want to check (e.g.: TRUE or FALSE) if I still have some of the "wavelength" sequences in the normal format or backward (this will be useful for other identical data frames).

This is how my data looks like (most of it):

| targt_ID | ID | wavelength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c1 | 350 |
| 1 | c1 | 351 |
| 1 | c1 | 352 |
| 1 | c1 | ... |
| 1 | c1 | 2998 |
| 1 | c1 | 2999 |
| 2 | c2 | 350 |
| 2 | c2 | 351 |
| 2 | c2 | 352 |
| 2 | c2 | ... |
| 2 | c2 | 2998 |
| 2 | c2 | 2999 |
| ........ | .. | .... |

This is how my data looks like (in specific "ID"):

| targt_ID | ID | wavelength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | t5 | 2999 |
| 46 | t5 | 2998 |
| 46 | t5 | 2997 |
| 46 | t5 | ... |
| 46 | t5 | 351 |
| 46 | t1 | 350 |
| 47 | t7 | 2999 |
| 47 | t7 | 2998 |
| 47 | t7 | 2997 |
| 47 | t7 | ... |
| 47 | t7 | 351 |
| 47 | t7 | 350 |
| ........ | .. | .... |

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Once you've done `arrange(targt_ID, wavelength)`, you should have (by definition of `arrange`) no decrement of `wavelength` within a particular `targt_ID`. This assumes that `wavelength` is `numeric` (or int); if it is `character`, though, that's different, since `"2000" < "350"` is true.

Comment: you may have a point since this data frame was built adding several data frames and for some reason, some wavelength columns might be formatted as a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be trust that `arrange()` is giving you the result you are looking for. If you want to double check, see the code below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create some unsorted data, resembling your original data.
unsorted_data <-
  tibble(ID = gl(5, 3),
         value = sample(350:2999, 15))

# Here we create a "lagged" variable of the values, that lets us compare  
# the value in each row with the value of the previous row. `going_up` stores
# the result of the conditional of `value` being bigger than `lagged` (previous value.).

unsorted_data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(lagged = lag(value),
         going_up = value > lagged) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(going_up)) %>% # Filter out the first row for each ID.
  pull(going_up) %>% 
  all()
#> [1] FALSE
```

This evaluates to `FALSE` as some of the values are smaller than the
values in the previous row.

```r
sorted_data <-
  unsorted_data %>%
  arrange(ID, value)

sorted_data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(lagged = lag(value),
         going_up = value > lagged) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(going_up)) %>% 
  pull(going_up) %>% 
  all()
#> [1] TRUE
```

The second result evaluates to `TRUE` meaning that each value in a row is
higher than the value in the previous row, within the values for one ID.